# Python - Iterating over nested JSON data problems

Tags: python, json

I am learning Python and am having some issues with iterating through a json data file, to get at certain keys and values. I do this all the time in PHP but am finding it a bit challenging in Python for some reason. I've tried a few things from Stack Overflow, but I feel I must be missing a fundamental here. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Here is my JSON data, which I am loading in from a file:

```
{
  "pfcProductfeed": {
    "productfeed": {
      "models": [
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "1",
            "description": "Product 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "2",
            "description": "Product 2"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "3",
            "description": "Product 3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is iterate through each of the "models" and display the modelCode and description for each model, in a loop. I've tried this:

```
import json

with open('data/stack.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

models = data['pfcProductfeed']['productfeed']['models']
print(json.dumps(models, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

for model in models:
    #print(json.dumps(model, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    print(model['description']) #How do I get at the keys, and their values
```

But this reports the error:

print(model['description']) #How do I get at the keys, and their values
KeyError: 'description'

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to iterate through this correctly?

Many Thanks

James

Comment: `model['model']['description']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `for model in models:` model is an object of the array. Meaning for exemple the first `model` will be :

```
{
    "model": {
        "modelCode": "1",
        "description": "Product 1"
    }
}
```

So if you want print the keys of `model`, you'll have `['model']`

If you want your `model` being that :

```
{
        "modelCode": "1",
        "description": "Product 1"
}
```

you can then use

```
for model in models:
    description = model['model']['description']
```

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
data = {
  "pfcProductfeed": {
    "productfeed": {
      "models": [
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "1",
            "description": "Product 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "2",
            "description": "Product 2"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": {
            "modelCode": "3",
            "description": "Product 3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

models = data['pfcProductfeed']['productfeed']['models']
for model in models:
  print(model['model']['description'])
```

output

```
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
```

Comment: Thankyou. I assumed that the for model in models: line meant that I was already at the correct level within the data. I believe this is how it works when I do similar in PHP. Thanks for your help! I'll give it a go!